# use environment variable in groovy script in SOAPUI script assertion

Tags: groovy, soapui, assertions

In script assertion of a test step in SOAP UI, I am using

```
def currentLoc = context.expand( '${#Global#xsd_loc}' )
new File( currentLoc+'\\application.xsd' ).withReader
```

here xsd_loc is defined in Global Properties is preferences

But if I declare that property in environment variable in user variables and call it using #Env# then it doesn't work.

Comment: What platform is that? I've used this Groovy: `println System.getProperty('java.home')` ===>
/usr/java/server-jre-1.8.0_25-0/jre
`println System.getenv('JAVA_HOME')` ===>
 /usr/java/server-jre-1.8.0_25-0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if you're setting your variable correctly in your enviroment. If for example I use this groovy script in SOAPUI:

```
def java_home = context.expand('${#Env#JAVA_HOME}');
log.info java_home
```

I'm getting the correct result:

```
Thu Aug 14 09:24:01 CEST 2014:INFO:C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60
```

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 0):

If you defined property in Preferences -> Global Properties then you can use it just like `${xsd_loc}` without specifying level `#Global`.